# Razor Dynamic Query & WebCache

Tags: c#, caching, dynamic, razor, webmatrix

I created the following code in a Razor view.

```
var Db= Database.Open("db");
var results = from t in Db.Query("up_rpt_hourlysales_today")
  group t by t["Channel"];
```

I'm using the data with the with following code...

```
@foreach (var c in results ){ 
    var htmlKey = Server.UrlEncode(c.Key);
  <p><a href="@htmlKey" data-role="button">@c.Key</a></p>
}
```

I wanted to use the WebCache so I added the following code.

```
var cacheItemKey = "Sales"; 
var cacheHit = true; 
var results = WebCache.Get(cacheItemKey); 

if (results == null) { 
    cacheHit = false; 
} 

if (cacheHit == false) { 
    var Db= Database.Open("db");
    results = from t in Db.Query("up_rpt_hourlysales_today")
                    group t by t["Channel"];

    WebCache.Set(cacheItemKey,results, 5,false);
}
```

The caching code works well, but when interating through the results I get an error when trying to access the Dynamic properties of the item.

*'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'*

I think that this is because the inital returning result type is Null and the Dynamic type is not updated when I set the result to it using the LINQ query.

Other than setting the type of *results* is there a way arround this?

Thanks

Brent

Comment: **BTW**: you're accessing the DB directly from the view? Is it the best architecture? Couldn't you perform that at the Controller and simply pass your items collection to the view?

Comment: That would be true if i had more than just this one page... Complexity for complexities sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your `Database.Query` method call is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>object, object>>` sequence (because of the group by operation), each element of which has a `Key` property. The WebCache is a collection of `object` types, just like Session etc, and these don't have a `Key` property so you need to cast the item back to its original type:

```
var cacheItemKey = "Sales"; 
var cacheHit = true; 
var results = (IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>>)WebCache.Get(cacheItemKey); 

if (results == null) { 
    cacheHit = false; 
} 

if (cacheHit == false) { 
    var Db= Database.Open("db");
    results = Db.Query("up_rpt_hourlysales_today").GroupBy(t => t.Channel);
    WebCache.Set(cacheItemKey,results, 5,false);
}
```

Comment: this works great.. -- however i needed to use the following cast to get this to work correctly.. 

    (IEnumerable<IGrouping<dynamic, dynamic>>)

Answer (score 1):

WebMatrix.Data is built on the top of the [dynamic features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) of .net. In you first sample the `Db.Query` method returns a collection of dynamic objects that's why in your loop the `c.Key` will resolve dynamically and works.

But when you put your result in the `WebCache` it handles the `results` as a `object`. So when you write

`var results = WebCache.Get(cacheItemKey);`

The static type of `results` will be `object` but the runtime type will be still the original collection that's why the `foreach` still works, but the `c.Key` call will fail because there is no dynamic dispatching involved.

To enable/force the dynamic dispatching declare `results` as `dynamic` of or use `dynamic` in your foearch:

```
@foreach (dynamic c in results ){ 
    var htmlKey = Server.UrlEncode(c.Key);
  <p><a href="@htmlKey" data-role="button">@c.Key</a></p>
}
```

Comment: I liked that idea of using the dynamic in the ForLoop, however when i tested it out, it didnt work correctly. Great explanation of the output of WebCache.Get() In the end I cast the the WebCache.Get result. Thank you.